# How to disable check out if document status is pending?

Tags: document-library

I have installed **Sharepoint Foundation 2010** and configured a Shared Document Library to support versioning and approval.

Now I would like to disable the possibility for a user to check out a document, if there is already document with approval status **Pending**.

Is it possible? Do I need to develop a custom web part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a custom SPItemEventReceiver to trap the ItemCheckingOut event, perform your check and cancel the operation (and event display a message to the user) if the approval status column is "Pending".

Here is a walkthrough: [Developing an Event Receiver for a Document Library](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/event-receivers-walkthrough2/)